# iOS7 Black Keyboard flickers from Default Appearance when Resuming from Background

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, ios7, uikeyboard

For I set the keyboard for my `UITextField` in Interface builder to be the dark style appearance. Lets say my view is A. When I go to view B, then go to the background, then resume with view B being present. I know launch view A, and view A's keyboard is momentarily the Default appearance and then goes to black. Does anyone know how to make the keyboard not experience this flicker? I'm using `NSNotificationCenter` events to set the text field as first respondent. I use `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` as suggested elsewhere, but, no luck.